# How to display the whole list of several items on a freemarker line?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, freemarker

How to display the whole list of two or three elements on a freemarker line. To display multiple elements in a row at the first iteration and the following elements at subsequent iterations?
[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can only display the entire list, i.e. take and fill one element each, and here to display them with a grid, I need to alternate 3 elements each, I don’t know how to do it (

Comment: Also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk

Comment: Thanks, I think, but now I will try)